# ui-view is undefined and my page is blank when i use ui routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I cannot see my index page till I  uncomment my code in controller.What am i doing wrong.here is my sample code.I have tried all possible options, not getting where am i going wrong

`

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var abc = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"])

      .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
          $stateProvider.state('home',{
            template: '<h1>This template is displayed with Ui route </h1>'
          });
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      }).
      controller('myNewCtrl',function($scope,$state){
//        $state.go('home');
      });
    </script>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="myNewCtrl">

    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: i dont get any error on the console

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("home", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<h1>This template is displayed with Ui route </h1>",
        controller: "myNewCtrl"
      });
});
myApp.controller('myNewCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <nav>
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  </nav>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can navigate when i use go or sref method, but how do we navigate to default template without using these two methods, using go works for me for now but later i have to declare abstract on home state and we cannot navigate to abstract sate by using go method in controller

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("home", {
        template: "<h1>This template is displayed with Ui route </h1>",
        controller: "myNewCtrl"
      });
});
myApp.controller('myNewCtrl',['$scope','$state', function($scope,$state) {
  $state.go('home');
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myNewCtrl">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes if we uncomment it works, but why should i route it from controller, according to docs it should load by default right